# Wildfly domain mode debug

Tags: eclipse, debugging, cluster-computing, wildfly

I have tried to configure widfly for remote debugging in domain mode, using Eclipse, but it's not successful. Does anyone know the detail configuration for Wildfly domain mode debugging with Eclipse. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

It depends on what you want to debug :

- to debug the Host Controller (that means the server that manages the domain) use the **domain.conf** file or set the environment variable PROCESS_CONTROLLER_JAVA_OPTS

  PROCESS_CONTROLLER_JAVA_OPTS="$PROCESS_CONTROLLER_JAVA_OPTS -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8788,server=y,suspend=n"
- to debug a s**erver instance** of your domain you have to pass jvm args in your host.xml, for example too debug server-one

  <server name="server-one" group="main-server-group">
      <jvm name="default">
          <jvm-options>
                <option value="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n"/>
          </jvm-options>
      </jvm>
  </server>

Answer (score 2):

To debug the server instance, you need to setup the JVM Configuration of the server group.

For this, using Wildfly Management (like http://{ip}:9990/console/App.html):

1. Access Wildfly Management from your Wildfly
2. Click on **Runtime**
3. Choose the server group from the list and click on **View**
4. Choose the **JVM Configuration** tab and click on **Edit**
5. On **JVM Options** put this line: `-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n`
6. Save the modifications and reload the server group.

To connect to the server, use the port 8787.

Comment: Use `address=*:8787` to bind the agent to all interfaces (not just localhost).